# CSS3 inner lighting for input

Tags: css

I need to make rounded inputs with inner lighting like on this picture:

[image]

I can make the rounding like this:

```
.loginRounded{
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

But I can't imagine how to make inner lighting with css3.

PS If it's impossible the last way is to use the image as a background.

**UPD**

Done with box-shadow attribute. But my variant still not the same with psd-layout...

[image]

**UPD2**
Finally done http://jsfiddle.net/Z3SB9/1/ - and the last question - in what browsers it will work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-shadow: inset` is what you are looking for, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Z3SB9/ and play with the values!

Comment: IE9+ and all other modern browsers (afaik)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a linear gradient, moz example:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eacfaf 0%, #FFF 50%);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dnxy2/1/